# ng-onclick appears to know about changes before $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I keep running into a problem where I need to pass through properties on $scope through an ng-click in order to have access to the property within the ng-click method. One of the issues is that $scope.rejectionMessage never appears to update.

Portion of HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input
        type="text"
        ng-model="rejectionMessage"
        ng-change="logWTF(rejectionMessage)"
        placeholder="Enter rejection message here."
    >
</label>
<button
    type="button"
    class="button button-block button-outline button-assertive"
    ng-click="rejectChild(rejectionMessage)"
>
    REJECT
</button>
```

Portion of Controller:

```
$scope.logWTF = function(rejectionMessage){
    console.log($scope.rejectionMessage) // messageA
    console.log(rejectionMessage) // messageB
}
```

messageA ($scope.rejectionMessage) is always an empty string, but messageB is always what is currently typed in the input.

The html has only 1 controller but it still appears that I have 2 separate $scope objects. I have debugged this and looked at all of the relevant $parentScopes and have not found the rejectionMessage property hiding anywhere unexpected.

A simple solution is to just pass the property through the function on the button ng-click method but I have other functions downstream that depend on $scope.rejectionMessage. I could pass it all the way through, but takes away a lot of value of Angular. Plus I'm relatively new to Angular and feel this will be a great learning experience for me.

EDIT: I just learned that all forms with name='something' use a separate controller and thus have their own $scope.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Actually, $scope. rejectionMessage never appears to update at all.

Question edited. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/oKoQ7NFYiBgmAehYxCFY?p=preview. It's most likely a typo

Comment: Thanks Phil. I've copied the exact string everywhere, and I've seen this exact behavior everywhere in my app. I don't think it's a typo, but it is something silly that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if the `input` is on a child scope of the controller's scope. It's called prototypal inheritance: reading `$scope.foo` reads upwards in the prototypal chain but writing to `$scope.foo`  will set it on that exact scope. So the `input` will set it on the child scope, the same as the button's, but not the same as the controller's.

The rule of thumb here is to set an object on the controller's scope, e.g. `$scope.model = {};`, and change the `ng-model` to `model.rejectionMessage`. Then you're sure you're referring to the `rejectionMessage` of the controller's scope. Some people say "Every ngModel should have a dot", because of this.

Comment: That's great advice. Thank you stevuu.

Comment: I have no idea how I ended up with 2 $scopes, but I just refactored and this fixed the issue. Thanks again.